# How to get Screen size in Flutter when my app running in Split screen mode

Tags: flutter, dart

Anyone has idea how to get screen size (App screen size) while the app is running in Split-screen mode.

Explanation : 
When I check screen size using MediaQuery.of(context).size it gives like 1080 X 480
Now If the app goes in split-screen mode the result is the same actually I want something like 540 X 480.

Comment: @Nilesh Senta you can measure your layout size :) at split mode

Answer (score 2):

You can use LayoutBuilder inside Scaffold and print the size using constraints property.
It will print whenever the screen size changes. For more visit [LayoutBuilder](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYDVcriKjsw)

```
 LayoutBuilder(builder: (builder, constraints) {
  print(constraints.maxWidth);
  }
```